# Prove $1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 > 0$

Tags: inequality, polynomials

Here is the question:

> a) Prove that $f(x) = 1 + x + x^2$ is positive for all $x$.
>
> b) Prove that $f(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4$ is positive for all $x$. You will probably need to consider separately the three cases $x \geq 0, x \leq -1$, and $-1 < x < 0$.
>
> c) Similarly prove that for all positive integers $n$, $f(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots + x^{2n-1} + x^{2n}$ is positive for all x.
>
> d) Prove that $x = -1$ is the only zero of $f(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots + x^{2n-1}$.

I can do part a) fairly easily but I'm stuck with the rest of them. I included part a) for some context as maybe you have to use it in the following parts.

This question is from Cambridge 3U Y11 and it's an "extension" question. It is in the 3rd chapter (Graphs and inequations) so a solution without calculus, sequence and series, and advanced polynomial theorums would be ideal but if this is too hard then any method is fine.

Thankyou

Comment: For part b) the identity $$1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4=\frac{x^5-1}{x-1}$$ for $x\ne1$ could be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving all parts at once:

---

As has already been mentioned, $1+x+\dots+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ comes in handy here.

Let $f_n(x)=1+x+\dots+x^n$. Then if $x \neq 1$, $f_n(x)=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$

$f_n(x)=0\implies$Clearly $f_n(1)\neq0$, so $1-x^{n+1}=0$

$$\implies x^{n+1}=1$$

$n$ even $\implies x=1$. But $f_n(1)\neq0$, so therefore there aren't any zeroes. Since $f_n(1)>0$, $f_n(x)$ is positive for all $x$.

$n$ odd $\implies x=\pm 1 \implies x=-1$. Verifying: $f_n(-1)=0$, and therefore it is only zero.

Answer (score 4):

What about $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 = x^2\left(x+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+\dfrac{3}{4}\left(x+\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^2+\dfrac{2}{3}\geq\dfrac{2}{3}>0.$

**Update:** Indeed, one can use the similar idea to bound $$f_n(x) = x^{2n}+x^{2n-1}+...+x^2+x+1 =x^{2n-2}\left(x+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+\dfrac{3}{4}x^{2n-4}\left(x+\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^2+$$$$+\dfrac{4}{6}x^{2n-6}\left(x+\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^2+\dots+ \dfrac{n+1}{2n}\left(x+\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^2+\dfrac{n+2}{2n+2}> 0.$$ Proving this is a straightforward induction on the sequence $$a_n = \dfrac{n+1}{2n},$$
which happens to satisfy the recurrence relation: $$a_{n+1} = 1-\dfrac{1}{4a_n}.$$
Therefore, we get the lower bound $f_n(x)>\dfrac{n+2}{2n+2},$ which I think is still not that close to the actual minimum value.

Comment: Cute. Can you do the same thing for all even n?

Comment: @martycohen yes, and it is updated. Turns out nothing special.

Answer (score 2):

Use the geometric series formula:
$$
1+x+\dots+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}
$$

If $n$ is even, show that $1-x^{n+1}$ has the same sign as $1-x$ for all nonzero $x$; since $1+x+\dots+x^n$ is clearly positive at $0$, this is enough to prove c) and therefore b).

If $n$ is odd, note that $1-x^{n+1}$ has only two real zeroes, namely $\pm 1$. Since $1+x+\dots+x^n$ is nonzero for $x=1$, this is enough to prove d).

Answer (score 2):

For (b), the three cases go as follows:

1. $x \ge 0$ is easy: all three terms $\ge 0$.
2. If $x \le -1$, $x^2 + x = (x+1) x \ge 0$ and $1 > 0$.
3. If $-1 < x < 0$, $x^2 > 0$ and $x + 1 > 0$.

The basic idea is the same for (c).

Answer (score 1):

$b)$ If $x = 0$ its true. Thus consider $x \ne 0$, then: $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4= x^2\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{1}{x}+1+x+x^2\right)= x^2\left(\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2+\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right) - 1\right)= x^2f(t), t = x+\dfrac{1}{x}, |t| \ge 2.$. If $t \ge 2 \implies f(t) \ge 2^2+2-1 = 5 > 0$, and if $t \le -2 \implies f(t) = t(t+1) - 1 \ge (-2)(-2+1) - 1 = 1 > 0$, and $x^2 > 0$ so $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4 > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

c) It's obvious that for $x\geq0$ we have $f(x)>0$.

Let $-1\leq x<0$.

Hence, $$f(x)=1+x+x^2(1+x)+...+x^{2n-2}(1+x)+x^{2n}>0.$$

Let $x<-1$.

Hence,
$$f(x)=x^{2n-1}(x+1)+x^{2n-3}(x+1)+...+x(x+1)+1>0$$
and we are done!